# Why does Rust fail to pick the right trait in this case?

Tags: rust, traits

Consider the following code:

```rust
use std::ops::Add;

trait Trait
    where Self::Assoc: Add<Self::Assoc, Output=Self::Assoc>
                     + for <'a> Add<&'a Self::Assoc, Output=Self::Assoc>
{
    type Assoc;
    fn get(&self) -> Self::Assoc;
}

fn add1<T: Trait>(x: T, y: T) -> T::Assoc {
    x.get() + y.get()
}
```

This fails to compile with:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:12:15
   |
12 |     x.get() + y.get()
   |               ^^^^^^^
   |               |
   |               expected reference, found associated type
   |               help: consider borrowing here: `&y.get()`
   |
   = note:    expected reference `&<T as Trait>::Assoc`
           found associated type `<T as Trait>::Assoc`
```

I'm able to work around the issue by explicitly specifying what trait I want to use:

```rust
fn add2<T: Trait>(x: T, y: T) -> T::Assoc {
    <T::Assoc as Add<T::Assoc>>::add(x.get(), y.get())
}
```

But I'm wondering: **why is this happening?** Also, is there any more compact work around?

Note that the order of the trait bounds matters. If I change them to:

```rust
    where Self::Assoc: for <'a> Add<&'a Self::Assoc, Output=Self::Assoc>
                     + Add<Self::Assoc, Output=Self::Assoc>
```

... then `add1` compiles fine, but this fails:

```
fn add3<T: Trait>(x: T, y: T) -> T::Assoc {
    x.get() + &y.get()
}
```

[Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9e4cdfb8073054f28d39ac2b474a1a7f)

Comment: Seems like [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54296) issue. I believe it is not a high priority to fix this, as it can in the majority of cases easily be worked around. Annoying though.

Comment: _"Also, is there any more compact work around?"_ -- You will need to be a bit clearer about exactly you want to achieve. A workaround could be to just dereference `y` when adding. I guess that's not what you want, but I can't deduce your abstraction requirements.

Comment: @L.Riemer: you're probably right

Comment: @PeterHall: ideally I would like to write the `+` operator, avoid any verbose `<... as ...>` forms, and still use the correct trait (referencing/dereferencing would switch to another trait, which will execute different code and might have a performance impact)

Comment: I believe all these inference problems have been deferred until the new constraint solver engine [chalk](https://github.com/rust-lang/chalk) lands in the Rust compiler.